# the url change rule for the site 'orbi'

Tags: url, web-crawler

I'd like to crawl the posts on the website called "orbi" for my research. To perform static web crawling, I need to know the URL addresses of the posts, and to crawl multiple posts, I need to understand how the URL addresses change, if at all. In most cases, URLs change in descending order. For example, there's a post with the URL https://orbi.kr/00064638460/. Typically, the URL of the next post written immediately after this one would be https://orbi.kr/00064638461/. However, on this 'orbi' website, the URL of the next post is https://orbi.kr/00064638464/. And the URL of the post after that is https://orbi.kr/00064638466/. I'm wondering if it's possible to perform static web crawling when the website's URLs change irregularly like this, or if there are unknown URL change patterns that I'm not aware of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The website following some different mechanism to generate post ID. It will be hard to identify the pattern and decode the next post ID. We should have a dynamic crawler which will give us the post ID for a given category and use those post IDs to crawl further information that we need.

Steps:

1. Crawl the post IDs dynamically from this page https://orbi.kr/list
2. Now fetch and extract required data from the above list of post IDs